# My Blazor Server App Windows Authentication works when I open the page on the server. When page opened on another domain PC, credentials are not asked

Tags: windows, authentication, iis, blazor, windows-authentication

I have activated in the Project properties "Enable Windows Authentication" When I open my pages on a browser in the server (where my app is hosted) then credentials are asked, that means working fine. But when I open my pages on another PC in the same intranet domain, no login Window appears. The pages are opened directly. What is missing in my project settings? My app is hosted in IIS

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication7.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: Have you also enabled Anonymous Authentication, which allows Windows Authentication to be bypassed? It is recommended to provide the  web.config file including authentication related configuration.

Comment: @JennyDai No only Windows Authentication is selected. I have added the conf. to my post

Comment: web.config does not contain all the settings of iis, you can check the relevant configuration in the applicationHostconfig file again, the current information is still too little to determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: @JennyDai One question if you allow: If I select just Windows Authentication in the project settings, and also enable Windows Auth. in IIS (Response=HTTP 401 Challange),as in my case, what should be the normal response if I enter my page? Should I be asked for username/password or not? I am a little bit confused now. Is the functionality of Windows Authentication just to get the logged in user name  for Windows, or should it really ask me again for username and password?

Comment: Windows Authentication is normally handled by IIS. This is the way it works: 
1. Client requests the page.

2. IIS returns a HTTP 401 response, with a header saying that it accepts Windows auth.
3. The client's browser automatically resends the request with the users credentials (as long as the site is trusted).
4. IIS verifies the user and passes the credentials to the application.
This is all designed to be seamless.